# Inherit properties to a WPF Page element

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This may be a very simple question, so my apologies.

My problem here is that I want to build a Multilingual `WPF` App using C#, but I don't know how to make my different `Page` elements inherit the same method which makes my MainWindow translate to different languages. The app is done, I'm just translating it to English **(My native language is Spanish)**.
I'm using `Resource files` to translate it.

**Code for the language translation:**

```
    private void Languages_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
//This is the combobox in which you select the language to display the app in
        Set_Language();            
    }

//This is the method to invoke the Resource Manager and all the stuff from the resource file.    
private void Set_Language()
    {
        if (!boolInit)
        {
            strLanguage = "LeitProjekteV2._0.Languages." + ((ComboBoxItem)LanguageSel.SelectedItem).Name.ToString();
            ResourceManager LocRm = new ResourceManager(strLanguage, typeof(MainWindow).Assembly);
            //Menu buttons
            lblMenu.Content = LocRm.GetString("strMainMenu"); //The names inside the "" are the names of the resource in the Resource file which, depending on the language selected(Spanish, English and German)
//Change the text of whatever I choose; in this case, a Label named 'lblMenu'
            MapButt.Content = LocRm.GetString("strMapButt");
            BuscButt.Content = LocRm.GetString("strBusButt");
            AgeButt.Content = LocRm.GetString("strAgeButt");
            ComButt.Content = LocRm.GetString("strComButt");
            InfButt.Content = LocRm.GetString("strInfButt");
            LoginButt.Header = LocRm.GetString("strLoginButt");
            RegisterButt.Header = LocRm.GetString("strRegisterButt");
            ContacButt.Header = LocRm.GetString("strContacButt");
            MasButt.Header = LocRm.GetString("strMoreButt");

//Here go the names of everything the Pages contain that I want to translate, just like above
//Have no idea how to inherit this method to all the pages
        }
    }
```

Now, I have several `pages` embedded in the same `MainWindow.xaml`, so that you click the `button` "Map", a `Frame` changes it's content to a `Page` named Map.xaml, and so on for other buttons.
But how do I make those `Pages` also translate?

Since the Set_Language() method takes the string value of the `Combobox` in order to select the correct `Resource File`, I don't want to create one combobox for every `Page` that I have, albeit that would eliminate my problem.

Any help? Sorry for the horrible way of asking, I'm still getting the hint here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below:

```
var wnd = Window.GetWindow(this); //get current window
```

Cast it to your window class and expose your language as a public property

Use your page to get the property by finding the current window

You may create a parent page class that do the above, and inheriting it for all your pages so you dont repeat code

Answer (score 0):

I can see the difficulty you are facing is that you can't find a way to *share* the combobox across the main window and the pages hosted in the frame.

You can set a global variable that is accessible from the whole application, a good place is in application settings. Then when you make a selection with the Combobox, you just update the selected value to that variable.

Then call each page's `Set_Language()` method when they are being loaded into the Frame. In the `Set_Language()` method of each page, you can query what is been set to the variable stored in the application settings.

If you want to quick solution, create a static class to hold the selected language is also OK.

```
static class UserSelections
{
    public static string Language { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This looks real promising, will definitely give it a try when I come back. Thanks man!